# Import error when importing modules into my node app

Tags: node.js

I am trying to import a package I got from npm called stellar js wallet (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stellar/wallet-sdk)
I'm using the exact code as instructed in their documentation which is below,

```
import {
  DepositProvider,
  WithdrawProvider,
  getKycUrl,
  TransferResultType,
} from "@stellar/wallet-sdk";

const withdrawProvider = new WithdrawProvider("<<Insert transfer server URL>>");

const supportedAssets = await withdrawProvider.fetchSupportedAssets();
```

and this is the entire error i get when i try to load it with node in command line

```
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test>node test.js
(node:10400) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test\test.js:1
import  WithdrawProvider from "@stellar/wallet-sdk";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

so my first guess was to follow the suggestion  in the error and rename it with a ",mjs" extension , but that doesn't help either, i get this error when i rename it

```
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test>node test.mjs
(node:13696) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test\node_modules\@stellar\wallet-sdk\dist\index.js:1
import * as Types from "./types";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:199:29)
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:152:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:177:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5)
```

so my last option was to add {type:module} to my package.json , but this is the directory my file is in

```
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test>dir
 Volume in drive C is Acer
 Volume Serial Number is 088D-6181

 Directory of C:\Users\Home\Desktop\test

06/16/2021  08:03 PM    <DIR>          .
06/16/2021  08:03 PM    <DIR>          ..
06/16/2021  02:01 PM    <DIR>          node_modules
06/16/2021  02:01 PM            21,879 package-lock.json
06/16/2021  08:03 PM               243 test.mjs
               2 File(s)         22,122 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  66,930,151,424 bytes free
```

as you can see i only have a package-lock.json, I'm not sure if that is the same thing, because when i opened the package-lock.json file i couldn't see how i could add it, it seemed out of place, so i don't know what I'm doing wrong but what can i do to get my node package working as i want it to? thanks much appreciated,

Comment: add a package.json and write it in it, if you use nodejs you should add this because its a project file and you can add depemndencies and keep track of them in it. the package lock is garbage but npm creates it if you install some packages

Answer (score 0):

To create a default `package.json` use the `npm init --yes` command in your folder ([npm documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-a-package-json-file))

After that edit it and add the line `"type": "module",`

Comment: i have used the npm init --yes to create the package.json and I edited it and added the line "type": "module",but I still got the error  "(node:11752) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\Home\Desktop\new\node_modules\@stellar\wallet-sdk\dist\index.js:1
import * as Types from "./types";"  I even renamed it with a .mjs extension  and used node --experimental-modules app.js to run it but still don't work, I'm suing node version 14, i don't know
^^^^^^

Comment: Your last error come from the package `@stellar/wallet-sdk` itself